# Exporting Raster and Vector Layers within ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, vector, export

I am looking for a geoprocessing tool or script that I can run within ArcMap that will extract all raster and vector layers by polygon shapefile and export them to a file.

This should give 609 exports since there are 609 distinct attributes of my polygon shapefile.

All my data layers are in one coordinate system. I wish for all the exports to carry this coordinate system as well.

I do not have the Spatial analyst extension.

Comment: Explore the help file and read up on modelbuilder, you can loop over data and do data extraction that way, it's what it is designed for.

Comment: Split by attribute?